# How can two similar functions have different polymorphic types in Haskell?

Tags: function, haskell, types, polymorphism, fibonacci

Im pretty much new to Haskell, so if Im missing key concept, please point it out.

Lets say we have these two functions:

```haskell
fact n
     | n == 0 = 1
     | n > 0  = n * (fact (n - 1))
```

The polymorphic type for `fact` is **`(Eq t, Num t) => t -> t`** Because `n` is used in the if condition and n must be of valid type to do the `==` check. Therefor `t` must be a `Number` and `t` can be of any type within class constraint `Eq t`

```haskell
fib n
    | n == 1 = 1
    | n == 2 = 1
    | n > 2  = fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)
```

Then why is the polymorphic type of `fib` is **`(Eq a, Num a, Num t) => a -> t`**?

I don't understand, please help.

Comment: Because you do not use the input parameters in your output.

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite get what you said. @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Haskell always aims to derive the *most* generic type signature.

Now for `fact`, we know that the *type of the output*, should be the same as the type of the input:

```
fact n | n == 0 = 1
       | n > 0  = n * (fact (n - 1))
```

This is due to the last line. We use `n * (fact (n-1))`. So we use a multiplication `(*) :: a -> a -> a`. Multiplication thus takes two members of the same type and returns a member of that type. Since we multiply with `n`, and `n` is input, the output is of the same type as the input. Since we use `n == 0`, we know that `(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool` so that means that that input type should have `Eq a =>`, and furthermore `0 :: Num a => a`. So the resulting type is `fact :: (Num a, Eq a) => a -> a`.

Now for `fib`, we see:

```
fib n | n == 1 = 1
      | n == 2 = 1
      | n > 2  = fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)
```

Now we know that for `n`, the type constraints are again `Eq a, Num a`, since we use `n == 1`, and `(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool` and `1 :: Num a => a`. But the **input `n` is never directly used in the output**. Indeed, the last line has `fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)`, but here **we use `n-1` and `n-2` as input of a new call**. So that means we can safely asume that the input type and the output type act independently. The output type, still has a type constraint: `Num t`: this is since we return `1` for the first two cases, and `1 :: Num t => t`, and we also return the addition of two outputs: `fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)`, so again `(+) :: Num t => t -> t -> t`.

Answer (score 5):

The difference is that in `fact`, you use the argument directly in an arithmetic expression which makes up the final result:

```
fact n | ...  = n * ...
```

IOW, if you write out the expanded arithmetic expression, `n` appears in it:

```
fact 3  ≡  n * (n-1) * (n-2) * 1
```

This fixes that the argument must have the same type as the result, because

```
(*) :: Num n => n -> n -> n
```

Not so in `fib`: here the actual result is only composed of literals and of *sub*-results. IOW, the expanded expression looks like

```
fib 3  ≡  (1 + 1) + 1
```

No `n` in here, so no unification between argument and result required.

Of course, in both cases you also used `n` to decide how this arithmetic expression looks, but for that you've just used equality comparisons with literals, whose type is not connected to the final result.

Note that you can also give `fib` a type-preservig signature: `(Eq a, Num a, Num t) => a -> t` is strictly more general than `(Eq t, Num t) => t -> t`. Conversely, you can make a `fact` that doesn't require input- and output to be the same type, by following it with a conversion function:

```
fact' :: (Eq a, Integral a, Num t) => a -> t
fact' = fromIntegral . fact
```

This doesn't make a lot of sense though, because `Integer` is pretty much the only type that can reliably be used in `fact`, but to achieve that in the above version you need to start out with `Integer`. Hence if anything, you should do the following:

```
fact'' :: (Eq t, Integral a, Num t) => a -> t
fact'' = fact . fromIntegral
```

This can then be used also as `Int -> Integer`, which is somewhat sensible.

I'd *recommend* to just keep the signature `(Eq t, Num t) => t -> t` though, and only add conversion operations where it's actually needed. Or really, what I'd recommend is to *not use `fact` at all* – this is a very expensive function that's hardly ever really useful in practice; most applications that naïvely end up with a factorial really just need something like [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), and those can be implemented more efficiently without a factorial.